# Proof Verification: Baby Rudin Ch. 6. Ex. 7a

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

I want to follow up on my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3787409/clarification-regarding-baby-rudin-chapter-6-exercise-7a). Based on the comments and responses I got for my previous question, I developed a new proof for Baby Rudin Ch. 6. Ex. 7a. The exercise is:

> Suppose $f$ is a real function on $(0, 1]$ and $f \in \mathscr{R}$ on $[c, 1]$ for every $c>0$. Define
> \begin{equation}\tag{7.0}
>     \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = \lim_{c \to 0} \int_{c}^1 f(x) \, dx
> \end{equation}
> if this limit exists (and is finite). If $f \in \mathscr{R}$ on $[0, 1]$, show that this definition of the integral agrees with the old one.

**My latest attempt:**

Firstly, we state a modified version of Theorem 6.12 (c) in the text; call it Theorem 6.12 (c$^*$). Theorem 6.12 (c) states that:

If $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$ and if $a<c<b$, then $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, c]$ and on $[c, b]$ and
\begin{equation*}
            \int_a^c f \, d\alpha + \int_c^b f \, d\alpha = \int_a^b f \, d\alpha
\end{equation*}

Now, if we allow for the possibility of $c=b$ in Theorem 6.12 (c), we obtain  Theorem 6.12 (c$^*$). To wit, take $c=b$ in Theorem 6.12 (c). Then,

If $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$ and if $a<c\le b$, then $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, c]$ and on $[c, b]$ and
\begin{equation*}
        \int_a^c f \, d\alpha + \int_c^b f \, d\alpha = \int_a^b f \, d\alpha + \int_b^b f \, d\alpha = \int_a^b f \, d\alpha
    \end{equation*}

In other words, we can safely replace $a<c<b$ with $a<c\le b$ in Th. 6.12. Now, we prove the original question.
Suppose $f$ is a real function and is Riemann integrable on $[0, 1]$ in the sense of the definition of Riemann integrals given on Pg. 121 in Rudin. Let $0<c\le1$ and that the limit on the right-hand side of (7.0) exists.

By Theorem 6.12 (c$^*$), $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[c, 1]$. We want to show that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{c \to 0} \int_{c}^1 f(x) \, dx = \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = \lim_{c \to 0} \int_{0}^1 f(x) \, dx 
\end{equation}

Let $\epsilon> 0$ be given. It suffices to that there exists a $\delta>0$ such that
\begin{equation}\tag{7.1}
    0< |c-0| < \delta \implies \left|\int_{c}^1 f(x) \, dx- \int_{0}^1 f(x) \, dx \right| < \epsilon
\end{equation}
By Theorem 6.12 (c$^*$), we know that $f$ is Riemann integrable on  $[0, c]$ and
\begin{equation}\tag{7.2}
    \int_0^c f(x) \, dx =  \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx - \int_c^1 f(x) \, dx
\end{equation}
Since $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0, c]$, it must also be bounded on $[0, c]$, for if $f$ is not bounded on $[0, c]$, then it cannot be Riemann integrable on $[0, c]$. Put $M = \sup\limits_{0 \, \le x \, \le c} |f(x)|$. Clearly, $M \ge 0$. If $M =0$, then $f(x) = 0 \, \forall x$, which implies
\begin{equation}
     \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx =0= \int_{c}^1 f(x) \, dx 
 \end{equation}
which means that the implication in (7.1) will hold for any $\delta$. So, assume WLOG that $0 < \epsilon\le M$. By Theorem 6.12 (d),we have
\begin{equation*}
    \left| \int_0^c f(x) \, dx\right| \le M(c-0) = Mc \stackrel{(7.2)}{\implies} \left| \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx - \int_c^1 f(x) \, dx\right| \le Mc
\end{equation*}
Put $\delta = \dfrac{\epsilon}{M}$. Notice that $c\in(0, 1]$ and $\dfrac{\epsilon}{M}\in(0, 1]$. If $c=\dfrac{\epsilon}{M}, Mc=\epsilon$ and
\begin{equation*}
    \left| \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx - \int_c^1 f(x) \, dx\right| \le Mc = \epsilon
\end{equation*}
If $c<\dfrac{\epsilon}{M}$, we have
\begin{equation*}
    \left| \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx - \int_c^1 f(x) \, dx\right| \le Mc < M \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{M} = \epsilon
\end{equation*}
If $c>\dfrac{\epsilon}{M}, \dots$

**My question**:

> Is Theorem 6.12(c$^*$) actually correct? If my proof correct, or is there something in the proof that can be improved? Can someone please suggest how the proof can be completed? Thanks!

Comment: As you've written it right now, the definition of $M$ depends on $c$ and the values of $c$ depend on $M$.  This is a problem.  Better to define $M$ independent of $c$ ... Related, the statement "If M=0, then f(x)=0∀x" is false, but if you define $M$ differently, it may become true...

Comment: @BrianMoehring I've tried to edit my proof based on your comment; however, I am having trouble completing it now. I think I will need to redefine $\delta$ to be something of the form $\delta = \min (\frac{\epsilon}{M}, \textrm{some other term})$, but I can't quite figure out what the new definition of $\delta$ should be. I'd be really grateful if you can provide a hint on how the current version of the proof can be completed.

Comment: I was hinting at setting $$M = \sup_{0 \le x \le 1} |f(x)|$$  From here, we have for any $0<c<1$, $$\left|\int_0^c f(x) \, dx \right| \leq Mc \to 0 \quad \text{as } c \to 0^+$$ which is all you needed to show, in light of the 6.12(c) you quoted, and the squeeze/sandwich theorem (just used for convenience)

Comment: @BrianMoehring Can $c$ not equal $1$ (you have strict inequality in $c<1$ in your last comment)?

Comment: It can equal $1$ but since we're taking a limit as $c\to 0^+$, it doesn't matter for the problem.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thanks, the question is resolved!

Comment: What is $\mathscr R$?

Comment: @miracle173 The set of all functions that are Riemann integrable; this is the same as Rudin's notation.